# App runs smoothly in debug mode but crashes in release mode

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm an Android newbie running an app using the latest Android Studio and Genymotion on Windows 7. I recently added Startapp ads to my app. When I run the app during debug, it runs smoothly and shows my ad. When I run it in release mode, I get a NullPointerException.

The log tells me that the error is in MainActivity.onCreate, but doesn't indicate the offending code. What could I have overlooked? My log file is shown below.

```
01-31 13:30:13.789    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.n.onSearchRequested
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve interface method 8471: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.n.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve interface method 8475: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-31 13:30:13.793    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-31 13:30:13.857    2992-2994/com.censored D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 3% free 8211K/8455K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 40ms
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/net/wifi/ScanResult;.timestamp
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve instance field 91
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x53 at 0x0011
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.os.StatFs.getBlockSizeLong, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.g.a
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 747: Landroid/os/StatFs;.getBlockSizeLong ()J
01-31 13:30:13.869    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002c
01-31 13:30:13.873    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.g.a
01-31 13:30:13.873    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8595: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (Z)V
01-31 13:30:13.873    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
01-31 13:30:13.877    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.provider.Settings$Global.getInt, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.g.a
01-31 13:30:13.877    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve static method 768: Landroid/provider/Settings$Global;.getInt (Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;)I
01-31 13:30:13.877    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001d
01-31 13:30:13.881    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.g.a
01-31 13:30:13.881    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 240: Landroid/content/Context;.checkSelfPermission (Ljava/lang/String;)I
01-31 13:30:13.881    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/net/wifi/ScanResult;.venueName
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve instance field 92
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0006
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method android.provider.Settings$Global.getInt, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.g.d
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve static method 769: Landroid/provider/Settings$Global;.getInt (Landroid/content/ContentResolver;Ljava/lang/String;I)I
01-31 13:30:13.885    2992-2992/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: forceOfferWall3D
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.l.as.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.l.as.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.c.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.f(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.d(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.s.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.startapp.android.publish.s.a(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.censored.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-31 13:30:13.973    2992-2992/com.censored W/System.err? at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 13:30:13.981    2992-2992/com.censored D/AndroidRuntime? Shutting down VM
01-31 13:30:13.985    2992-2992/com.censored W/dalvikvm? threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6287288)
01-31 13:30:14.001    2992-2992/com.censored E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.censored/com.censored.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.startapp.android.publish.l.as.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.c.i.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.f(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.d(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.ai.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.s.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.startapp.android.publish.s.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.censored.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 13:30:14.065    2992-3019/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.a.c
01-31 13:30:14.065    2992-3019/com.censored W/dalvikvm? VFY: unable to resolve static method 11240: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
01-31 13:30:14.069    2992-3019/com.censored D/dalvikvm? VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0004
01-31 13:30:14.173    2992-2994/com.censored D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 353K, 6% free 8271K/8711K, paused 12ms+48ms, total 104ms
01-31 13:30:14.721    2992-2994/com.censored D/dalvikvm? GC_CONCURRENT freed 339K, 5% free 8392K/8775K, paused 20ms+12ms, total 40ms
01-31 13:30:16.685    2992-2992/? I/Process? Sending signal. PID: 2992 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: `2992-3019/com.censored I/dalvikvm? Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.startapp.android.publish.l.a.c`.

Comment: the error is before that.

Comment: He missed to set `ads:adUnitId`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have some asynchronous code that set the value of some variables ? In debug mode the timings are going to be different than release mode and async chose may not finish to execute before you want to use some variables assigned in the async part.